# If $A$ and $B$ are mutual inverses, then what is $A^{22}B^{20}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This came up in a test and I want to make sure with my answer.

> Given: $A= B^{-1}$, then $AB=BA=I$
>
> Find: $A^{22}B^{20}$

Since $AB$ gives the identity matrix what I assumed is that
$A^nB^n=I^n=I$

Hence I was left with $I A^2 = A^2$.

Comment: $A^nB^n$ is indeed equal to $I^n$, but this is a special thing. In general, if you have $AB=C$, then you do not necessarily have $A^nB^n=C^n$, so be careful with this!

Comment: Also, note that I changed "inversible" to "mutual inverses" to make the title clearer. Hope it's fine with you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right.

**Proposition.** *If $A=B^{-1}$, then $A^nB^n=I$, for integers $n>0$.*

Proof by induction on $n$. It is plainly true for $n=1$.

Suppose it holds for $n$. Then
$$
A^{n+1}B^{n+1}=A^nABB^{n}=A^nIB^n=A^nB^n=I
$$

You should however write
$$
A^{22}B^{20}=A^2A^{20}B^{20}=A^2I=A^2
$$
to be more formal.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, but be careful with your statement of proof. You wrote
$$
    A^nB^n=I^n=I
$$
and this is a little slapdash with the ordering. You can do this since $A$ and $B$ commute, ie $AB$ = $BA$ but you couldn't if they didn't. The other answers have been very careful to show that $A^nB^n=I$ is true even if $A$ and $B$ don't commute.

Comment: I wonder what matrices satisfy that $A^nB^n=I$ but $AB\neq BA$. (I don't say it's impossible, but I don't see an example.)

Comment: @yo' If $A$ and $B$ are $2\pi/n$ rotations in $\mathbb R^3$ they don't normally commute, but $A^n$ and $B^n$ are $2\pi$ rotations that is $A^n=B^n=I$ so clearly $A^nB^n=I$ then.

Comment: @skyking That's a nice one, 100% clear, thanks. Then a similar example can be found amongst the permutation matrices, with the bonus of being real-valued (even integer-valued). Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the $A$s and $B$s just cancel one after the other:

$$A^{22}B^{20}=A^{21}ABB^{19}=A^{21}B^{19}=A^{20}ABB^{18}=\dots=A^2AB=A^2$$